# If file contains certain text, how can I extract a string from the file and input it into a cell? (VBA)

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel

Say I have the following path and file name:

P:\...\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\ECMQA 2012Q1.xls

I want to write an if then statement that does the following (not sure if my statement is set up properly):

```
If InStr(1, "P:\...\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\ECMQA 2012Q1.xls", "QA", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").value = "2012Q1"
End If
```

Instead of just inputting "2012Q1", I want it to automatically read this from the file.  The thing is I am actually looping through 12 or so files and there's two types, "ECMQA 2012Q1.xls"  (or ECMQB 2012Q2.xls and so on)  AND "ECM Annual Budget 2012.xlsx"

If my file is the annual one (If file contains "Annual"), then I want:

```
BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").value = "2012"
```

And i want it to read this from the actual file, same as the other one...not me putting in "2012"

Is there a way to do this?

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the loop:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, sFile As String, sPath As String
Dim itm As Variant
Dim strFileNames  As String

sPath = "C:\Actuary\Cash Flow Forecast\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\"

''Retrieve the current files in directory
sFile = Dir(sPath)
Do While sFile <> ""
    strFileNames = strFileNames & "," & sFile
    sFile = Dir()
Loop

''Open each file found
For Each itm In Split(strFileNames, ",")
    If itm <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & itm)

        ''DO LOTS OF CALCULATIONS

        'wb.Close True
    End If
Next itm
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you say *read this from the file*, do you mean read from the filename or read from inside the actual file? Also, can you show us the loop? (*I am actually looping through 12 or so files*) The more information you provide, the easier it is to help out.

Comment: @Olle  Check the edit for the loop.  When I said "read this from the file" I meant from the file name.  Hope that clarifies things

Comment: There's nothing in the loop right now because I'm trying to see if my code works for one file and then I'm inputting everything in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filesystemobject has a method for extracting the base name from a filename:

```
Msgbox createobject("scripting.filesystemobject").getbasename("myTest.xlsx") 'myTest
```

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to get at what you need using split, right, left, mid, or even regex. It really depends on the makeup of the possible source strings and how much variation they contain.

Based soley on your example the following shows various manipulations with the last variable giving "2012"

```
Sub test()

fPath = "P:\...\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\ECMQA 2012Q1.xls"

fArray = Split(fPath, "\")
fnamewithtext = fArray(UBound(fArray))
fnamewithoutext = Split(fArray(UBound(fArray)), ".")(0)

ifannual = Left(Split(fArray(UBound(fArray)), " ")(1), 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: I can play around with that. Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned, this will work if the structure of the filenames are always the same, eg "nnnnnn YYYYQx.xlsx". I suggest you make a function or two for the different types of filenames.

Comment: @Olle There's two kinds of structures, the one above and the other one, as I mentioned is going to be in the "ECM Annual Budget 20xx.xlsx" structure.

Comment: Actually, if you put the code above in a function, it will work for both types of filenames right away, no need for more than one.